# Android Studio Cannot find JVM

Tags: android, android-studio

After using Android Studio for 3 or more years and always updating to latest version, builds began to slow down.  So I took the AS option of creating a vmoptions file, which AS does for you if one does not exist.

I entered an xmx value, attempted to restart AS. I got the message saying it failed to create JVM: error code 6.

Since then I have verified the `JAVA_HOME` value, checked that it points to the location of the Java jdk (jdk1.8.0_171).

AS still gives me the same error. I did a complete uninstall of AS and verified that it did a complete uninstall, downloaded latest version, and I still get same error. None of the suggested solutions have solved this problem.

My PC has 16Megs of memory. I have tried other JDK versions and had zero success. What do I have to do? Re-install Win 10 Pro 64 bit???

And yes, my JDK is the 64bit version and why has AS worked fine for the last 3+ years? Deleting the vmoptions file did not help.

Comment: AS also keeps settings in your user directory; no clue what it is on Windows, but you'd likely need to wipe that as well.

Comment: Thank you!! That fixed it. Now I can start working again.